# Pass form to multiple widgets

Tags: flutter

I'm building an app with a long form in it. So I decided to seperate it into several steps.
Each step would be a widget containing formFields.

So I would have something like this:

```
int _currentStep = 0;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _firstname;
  String _lastname;
  String _city;

  List<Widget> formGroups = [
    FormGroup1(),
    FormGroup2(),
    FormGroup3(),
  ];
```

The form would bind to the state like this

```
Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: formGroups[_currentStep],
),
```

My idea is to be able to navigate to the next widget like this

```
  void goToNext() {
    setState(() {
      if (_currentStep < formGroups.length - 1) {
        _currentStep += 1;
      }
    });
  }
```

Firstly, is it a good practice?
How can I get the main widget to get the input from the children widgets?
For example if the FormGroup2 contains the inputfield to set the _lastname, how can I make it availaibe at the form level?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `"So I decided to seperate it into several steps."` - tried `Stepper` class?

Comment: no. a multi step form

Comment: sorry I have no idea what "multi step form" is

Comment: I mean instead of having a huge form, I'll break it into a group of fields that I display conditionally

Comment: this is what `Stepper` class is used for: *"A material stepper widget that displays progress through a sequence of steps. Steppers are particularly useful in the case of forms where one step requires the completion of another one, or where multiple steps need to be completed in order to submit the whole form."*

Comment: Looks more convenient. Thank you! i'll give it a try

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you want parent widget to get input from the child widget you always use the `NotificationListener` at parent and pass `Notification` containing data from the child.

This technique is used by many flutter widgets like `DefaultTabController` receives `OverscrollNotification` when user swipes to the last page and is still trying to swipe.

In your use case you can pass the value notifications from the child Widgets to the Form Widget.

Here is a Demo for your reference [***Run on dartpad***](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/72e9aa09f519fc0f0a60fde44c4f4328)

Following is a working code demonstrating the use of this widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _string = 'You haven\'t pressed a button yet' ;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Notification demo'),),
      body: NotificationListener<IntegerNotification>(
        onNotification: (IntegerNotification notification){
          print(notification.value);
          setState(() {
            _string = 'You have pressed button ${notification.value} times.';
          });
          return true;
        },
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_string),
            ChildWidget(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Increment'),
        onPressed: () {
          IntegerNotification(++_counter).dispatch(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IntegerNotification extends Notification {
  final value;

  IntegerNotification(this.value);
}
```

I hope this helps, in case of any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thank you @Kalpesh 
I'll try it out and let you know how it went. Cheers

Comment: If it works for you don't forget to accept and up-vote the answer..